# SharePoint 2013 Activity Event in Newsfeed

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, feed, mysite

I need to add custom notifications to the personal Newsfeed on people's MySites. I found several tutorials and code examples for SharePoint 2010 on the net and tried to do the same with SharePoint 2013. They're all about creating `ActivityEvents` with the `ActivityManager`.

Here's the code I tried:

```
        var targetSite = new SPSite("URL to MySite webapp");
        SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(targetSite);
        var userProfileManager = new UserProfileManager(context);

        var ownerProfile = userProfileManager.GetUserProfile("domain\\user1");
        var publisherProfile = userProfileManager.GetUserProfile("domain\\user2");

        var activityManager = new ActivityManager(ownerProfile, context);

        Entity publisher = new MinimalPerson(publisherProfile).CreateEntity(activityManager);
        Entity owner = new MinimalPerson(ownerProfile).CreateEntity(activityManager);
        ActivityEvent activityEvent = ActivityEvent.CreateActivityEvent(activityManager, 17, owner, publisher);
        activityEvent.Name = "StatusMessage";
        activityEvent.ItemPrivacy = (int)Privacy.Public;
        activityEvent.Owner = owner;
        activityEvent.Publisher = publisher;
        activityEvent.Value = "HELLOOOO";
        activityEvent.Commit();

        ActivityFeedGatherer.BatchWriteActivityEvents(new List<ActivityEvent> { activityEvent }, 0, 1);
```

The Id `17` in the `CreateActivityEvent` function is for the `StatusMessage` activity type, which is layouted like `{Publisher} says: {Value}` in the ressource files, so I provide the `Value` property of my `ActivityEvent`.

The code runs without any exception and in the `User Profile Service Application_ProfileDB` database I can see the right entries appear in the `ActivityEventsConsolidated` table.
But the activity is not visible in the activity feed, neither on the Owner's one, nor on the Publisher's one, even though these people follow each other. I ran the Activity Feed Job in the CA manually to update the activity feed.
Also, I tried to do the same with custom `ActivityTypes` with own ressource files, same result: The entry in the `ActivityEventsConsolidated` table (or `ActivityEventsPublished` if Owner=Publisher) appear, but no entries on the MySite.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You may get more traction on this if you move this question to the Sharepoint StackExchange site. This is specific enough that the guys you want to answer this question are hanging out over there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this problem myself.
In `Central Administration`, `Setup MySites`, you have to enable the `Enable SharePoint 2010 activity migration` setting in the `Newsfeed` section in order to support SP1010 legacy activities in SP2013.